# Mark document as dirty in non-document based application

Tags: cocoa, menubar

I'm creating a simple Cocoa non-document based application. I want to show visually that the "document" app is working with has unsaved changes (the close button displaying a dot).

Is this possible to do without changing app's architecture to document based?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `[window setDocumentEdited:YES];`